# How to solve "We can't display this information because the record has no parent or you don’t have access"?

Tags: lightning-experience

We are observing a strange issue. If you view a record in LEX, the records History related list will show no records, like so:

[image]

However, if you click `Edit`, make no changes, and just click `Save`, when the popup goes away, the related list will show this:

[image]

The custom object is `Dealer Agreement` and the list is the standard history related list.

Refreshing the page makes this message go away. I don't believe this to be permission issues or problems related to page layout as it works initially but then shows the strange error.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what we can do about it, if anything?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

1.Check OWD and Crud/FLS.Ensure you have access to the parent record.

2.Page Layout of parent should have the related list.

3.The lookup field is included on the page layout of the child record

Comment: Thanks, but these are all fine. The issue is is works but when you edit the record, it shows that strange error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @clairvoyant's answer, make sure to make an edit to the columns selected for the related list's layout on the parent record (and revert it afterwards). Seems like salesforce keeps displaying the error if the related list already exists on the parent record.